# React-Native no such AndroidManifest.xml when "npx react-native run-android"

Tags: android, react-native

I was working on a react-native APP in the same environment for a long time, but my computer had a problem and I had to change it. I've been trying to run the same APP in the new environment for a few days (I haven't changed anything in the code and I believe I did the setup correctly)

The error follows:

```
BUILD FAILED in 33s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Unable to install /home/thallyssonklein/Desktop/Smartial/app/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Unknown failure: Error: Failed to parse APK file: /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
Exception occurred while executing:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: Failed to parse APK file: /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.setParamsSize(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:338)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:906)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:158)
at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:21328)
at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:634)
at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:532)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:2821)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:3856)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed to parse /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseApkLiteInner(PackageParser.java:1617)
at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseApkLite(PackageParser.java:1575)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.setParamsSize(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:331)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml
at android.content.res.ApkAssets.nativeOpenXml(Native Method)
at android.content.res.ApkAssets.openXml(ApkAssets.java:152)
at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseApkLiteInner(PackageParser.java:1594)
... 11 more
  at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installRemotePackage(Device.java:1143)
  at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:973)
  at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:949)
  at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:938)
  at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackage(ConnectedDevice.java:126)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.InstallVariantTask.install(InstallVariantTask.java:171)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.InstallVariantTask.lambda$doTaskAction$1(InstallVariantTask.java:102)
  at com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceProvider.use(DeviceProvider.java:53)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.InstallVariantTask.doTaskAction(InstallVariantTask.java:91)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:73)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:34)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:91)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask.taskAction(NonIncrementalTask.kt:34)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:49)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:42)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:721)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:688)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:539)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:524)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:507)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:258)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:247)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
  at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:63)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:49)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:34)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:43)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:44)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:54)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:38)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:153)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:67)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:41)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:44)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:33)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:85)
  at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:39)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:94)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:79)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:53)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
  at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:39)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:40)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:28)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:174)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:166)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:374)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:361)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:354)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:340)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Unknown failure: Error: Failed to parse APK file: /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
  Exception occurred while executing:
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: Failed to parse APK file: /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.setParamsSize(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:338)
  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:906)
  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:158)
  at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103)
  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:21328)
  at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:634)
  at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:532)
  at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:2821)
  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:3856)
  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
  Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed to parse /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseApkLiteInner(PackageParser.java:1617)
  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseApkLite(PackageParser.java:1575)
  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.setParamsSize(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:331)
  ... 9 more
  Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml
  at android.content.res.ApkAssets.nativeOpenXml(Native Method)
  at android.content.res.ApkAssets.openXml(ApkAssets.java:152)
  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseApkLiteInner(PackageParser.java:1594)
  ... 11 more

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 33s

    at makeError (/home/thallyssonklein/Desktop/Smartial/app/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /home/thallyssonklein/Desktop/Smartial/app/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/home/thallyssonklein/Desktop/Smartial/app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/home/thallyssonklein/Desktop/Smartial/app/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the hell but "npx react-native upgrade" solved the problem.